# Limit UITableView panning to 1 finger

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a scenario where I have two UITableViews as a subview in a main UIView:

UIView (frame = full screen)
+--- UITableView (frame = ~1/3 of the screen)
+--- UITableView (frame = second ~1/3 of the screen)

I want to detect a three finger swipe up on the whole screen area (and also allow the user to pan UITableViews up and down with at least one finger).

I have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer attached to UIView with `numberOfTouchesRequired = 3`.

I've tried these:

- Setting both internal UIPanGestureRecognizers `maximumNumberOfTouches` to 1 on both UITableViews. To my understanding this should prevent two and three finger pans on the UITableViews but it doesn't. (If I set `enabled` to NO on these UIPanGestureRecognizers, the touches are correctly passed to the superview. But then the panning/scrolling doesn't work.)
- Calling `panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` with my `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on both UITableViews. This works partly, but the panning waits until the swipe hasn't been completed and it feels very clumsy.
- Overriding UITableView with setting `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to return YES, which allows me to detect the three finger swipe. However, the UITableViews beneath pan/scroll up unintentionally.

So how do I limit the number of panning touches to 1 (or 2) and let the three-finger UISwipeGestureRecognizer recognize three finger swipes?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `canPreventGestureRecognizer:` on the top (whole screen) *UIPanGestureRecognizer*, returning `NO` for each of the two table view gesture recognizers.

I'd also try overriding `canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:` on each of the two table view gesture recognizers to return `NO` in the case of the topmost *UIPanGestureRecognizer*.

I've run into a similar situation as yourself quite a while ago and can't remember how I fixed it (the project is long gone), but I seem to remember playing around with the aforementioned methods and eventually getting it to work.